# The food is prepared or the food was prepared

Tags: grammar

I want to invite people to have meal, and the meal is ready. Should I say 'the food is prepared' or 'the food was prepared'?

Comment: What is the problem with "ready" though?

Comment: I‘m trying to use the other way to express.

Comment: "Grub's up"  .....

Answer (score 1):

The word prepared in the sentence is an adjective.  When you say the meal is prepared, it means that it's been made ready to be eaten, for example after cooking it.

The correct sentence is "the food is ready/prepared, not "...was ready/prepared", because you are talking of the present, not the past.